# Custom Javascript type with Rails and Slim

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

In Rails, both the javascript_tag and javascript_include_tag render the type attribute as

> type="text/javascript"

I need to customize this attribute. Our application uses [Slim](https://github.com/stonean/slim) syntax which makes this a little more difficult.

> script src="mathjax_config" type="text/x-mathjax-config"

^ doesn't error but doesn't even include the file

> javascript_tag[type="text/x-mathjax-config"] javascript code here

^ throws an error

I'm hoping to avoid breaking the file away from slim.

Ruby version 1.9.3
Rails version 3.2.3

Answer (score 1):

Since you are modifying the type attribute you would either need to override the javascript_tag helper or write your own for that to work. This syntax isn't as elegant but should work:

script src=asset_path("mathjax_config") type="text/x-mathjax-config"

Note that this is slim/haml syntax - YMMV in erb.

Answer (score 1):

The file not being included is not Slims fault. Slim is agnostic to the content of the attributes, so it will happily render

```
script src="mathjax_config" type="text/x-mathjax-config"
```

into

```
<script src="mathjax_config" type="text/x-mathjax-config"></script>
```

Also, as far as I know, the browsers should happily load scripts with types other than "text/javascript" and you should be able to access them using their id.

Your approach is correct and the script not being included must have a different reason (like the file specified in src cannot be found).