# Set Javascript Type in Ruby Slim File

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, slim-lang

I have a Ruby on Rails application with mailers that use slim for the views.

I want to mark up an email with the Google markup format.
It calls for a script tag with the type of JSON-LD, like this:
`<script type="application/ld+json">`

My email view is written in slim.  I know I can create a script tag that doesn't have a type set in slim by prefacing it with `javascript:`, but the type will not be set that way.

How can I set the type to JSON-LD in a slim template?

I want to put the Javascript in the script block rather than load it from a src, unlike the person who asked this question:
[Custom Javascript type with Rails and Slim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12926940/custom-javascript-type-with-rails-and-slim)

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could just use a regular script tag and escape the javascript:

```
script type="application/ld+json"
  | alert('hi’)
```

Or you could create a shortcut to accomplish this:

From https://github.com/slim-template/slim:

You can also set additional fixed value attributes to a shortcut.

```
Slim::Engine.set_options shortcut: {'^' => {tag: 'script', attr: 'data-binding',
  additional_attrs: { type: "text/javascript" }}}
```

Then

```
^products
  == @products.to_json
```

which renders to

```
<script data-binding="products" type="text/javascript">
    [{"name": "product1", "price": "$100"},
     {"name": "prodcut2", "price": "$200"}]
</script>
```